# Load external webpage in div and adjust height

Tags: jquery, html, web

I'm trying to load an external webpage into a div (#siteloader) with Jquery, but am having trouble figuring out how to adjust the height of the div so that re-sizes to fit the content of the external site without getting scroll bars. I definitely don't want to use iframes.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    object {
        width: 100%;
    }       
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="siteloader"></div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $("#siteloader")
            .html('<object data="https://system.netsuite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp?country=US">');
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i've done the same thing with an iframe. since i had control over the external HTML i added to the page function set_iframe_height(w) P $('#iframe-element').height(w); } and in the embedded page i added parent.set_iframe_height($('body').height());

Answer (score 2):

It's not your `div` not expanding, but your `object`. Try to fix that - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 99%;
}

object {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, there is a function called .load() which unfortunately cannot be used to retrieve any cross domain HTML.

You can call a AJAX GET to retrieve the HTML and get put it in your div.

Or you can try this mod: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

if you do not specific a height or width it will expand to the proper size automatically , I would recommend though , you set a `max-height` or `max-width` and `overflow: hidden` ,   this is just for scenerios to control where the content came in way too big , and over flow hidden will prevent scrollbars